# How to use the FindControl function to find a dynamically generated control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a PlaceHolder control inside of a ListView that I am using to render controls from my code behind.  The code below adds the controls:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = quest.Value;
tb.ID = quest.ShortName.Replace(" ", "");
((PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("ph_QuestionInput")).Controls.Add(tb);
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the values that have been entered into the TextBox:

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem di in lv_Questions.Items)
{
    int QuestionId = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)di.FindControl("hf_QuestionId")).Value);
    Question quest = dc.Questions.Single(q => q.QuestionId == QuestionId);
    TextBox tb = ((TextBox)di.FindControl(quest.ShortName.Replace(" ","")));
    //tb is always null!
}
```

But it never finds the control.  I've looked at the source code for the page and the control i want has the id:

ctl00_cphContentMiddle_lv_Questions_ctrl0_Numberofacres

For some reason when I look at the controls in the ListViewDataItem it has the ClientID:

ctl00_cphContentMiddle_lv_Questions_ctrl0_ctl00

Why would it be changing Numberofacres to ctl00?  Is there any way to work around this?

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify, I am databinding my ListView in the Page_Init event.  I then create the controls in the ItemBound event for my ListView.  But based on what @Womp and MSDN are saying the controls won't actually be created until after the Load event (which is after the Page_Init event) and therefore are not in ViewState?  Does this sound correct?

If so am I just SOL when it comes to retrieving the values in my dynamic controls from my OnClick event?

**UPDATE 2:**

So i changed the code i had in my Page_Init event from:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //databind lv_Questions
        }
}
```

to:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //databind lv_Questions
}
```

And it fixed my problem.  Still a little confused as to why I want to databind regardless of whether it's a postback or not but the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding your textbox to a `Placeholder` control... but then you're searching a `ListViewDataItem` container for it later.

Seems to me that you need to search for the Placeholder first, and then search it for the textbox.

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of the PlaceHolder control but I have checked into what you are talking about and when I find the PlaceHolder control it doesn't have any child controls.  Based on the last 5 lines of my posting i'm assuming that the TextBox control is there but has had it's id changed (from ending in Numberofacres to ending in ctl00).

Comment: Are you recreating the textboxes the exact same way (adding them to the same container, in the same order) on every postback?

Comment: I only create them when `!this.IsPostBack`. I am trying to retrieve any values entered into these controls in an OnClick button event.

Comment: If you don't create dynamic controls on the postback, they won't exist.  This explains why the textbox is null.  Remember that every request creates a *new* instance of your page class, with *new* instances of the controls in it.  You can't just create dynamic controls once, they won't be there next time.

Comment: Yeah that's true.  Do you have any idea on how I would retain the values entered into the dynamic controls so that i could do something with them in my OnClick event?

Comment: If you create your dynamic controls in the Page_Init handler the same way on every page request, then they will be registered for ViewState tracking, and the values will be populated normally.  If you don't create your controls until later, then they will populate with the posted values, but any changes you make to them won't be saved to ViewState.  Honestly, dynamic controls are a big can of worms, and I'd avoid them if you can.  Just adding static textbox controls and flipping their Visibility property on and off would be a lot easier if you can do it.

Comment: Also this overview of the page lifecycle will be immensely helpful if you can grok it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx Committing it to memory will make you a much better ASP.Net programmer, but the complexity of it is a huge failing of ASP.Net webforms.

Comment: Thanks Womp that helped clarify a lot of questions I had.  Take a look at my update and let me know if i'm understanding you.

Comment: Check out Update 2 to see how i resolved it.  Thanks for your help Womp!